# How to make a website inaccessible from Chrome?

Tags: windows-7, firefox, google-chrome, internet-explorer, hosts

Using the Windows OS's `host` file to redirect an URL to an invalid one, e.g. `127.0.0.1`, will help me to stop that URL in Internet Explorer and Firefox but not in Google Chrome.

How can I do that in the Chrome browser?

Comment: And why do you need to do this?  I don't see a point in having Chrome installed unless you're going to use it to browse the web.  That is what it's for, anyway.

Comment: @kokbira Will uninstall your comment first if possible ^_^

Comment: @ephilip I want to test my website my friend! My website has different UI based on which urls are accessible or not.

Comment: Are you putting "http://" or "https://" before hostname in URL bar? According to @thecoolestguy in http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=292fbe1492ac3e1a&hl=en it can be the problem... Another note:      
the question would be better if you change from "How to make a web inaccessible from Chrome?" to "How to make a web inaccessible from Chrome for an address?" or "How to redirect an url to an invalid one on Chrome?"..

Comment: Ohh, I'm sorry.  I was a bit mislead by your title.  It wasn't clear enough.  I thought you wanted to make the whole web inaccessible.  I suggested an edit to make your title clearer.

Answer (score 3):

Try clearing the cache in Chrome.

1. Browse to `chrome://settings/advanced`.
2. Click the **Clear browsing data...** button.
3. Check only the **Empty the cache** checkbox.
4. Click the **Clear browsing data** button.

Comment: In IE & Firefox, I don't need to clear any cache...

Comment: @NamGiVU Chrome has an internal DNS prefetcher & cache.

Comment: it is as Nalorin's solution http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=4440a09b8649b756&hl=en . try that :)